# Why are there only four elemental artefacts?

Tags: ninjago

What I mean by this is that there are only 4 golden weapons (Fire, lightning, earth and ice), 4 elemental weapons (the same elements), 4 elemental forges (the same ones) 4 obsidian weapons (again!).

Why are there only fire, lightning, earth and ice artefacts and not for example gravity, mind, smoke things? Why were the Fire, Lightning, Earth and Ice elemental warriors chosen to be ninjas and not for example Shadow or Nature?

Comment: Without a statement from TLG it is impossible to say. The inspiration behind the elements could be the classical elements of earth, air (lightning), fire and water (ice), but this is pure speculation without an answer from LEGO themselves.